# Controls vanish using dynamic layout

Tags: mfc

This is really odd! I have this dialog resource:

```
ID_DLG_ASSIGN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 415, 285
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Assignments"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    GROUPBOX        "Date Range ...",IDC_STATIC,7,9,120,91,0,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    LTEXT           "&Start Date:",IDC_STATIC,16,18,103,8
    CONTROL         "DateTimePicker1",ID_DTP_ASSIGN_FROM,"SysDateTimePick32",DTS_RIGHTALIGN | WS_TABSTOP,16,28,104,12
    LTEXT           "&End Date:",IDC_STATIC,16,43,103,8
    CONTROL         "DateTimePicker2",ID_DTP_ASSIGN_TO,"SysDateTimePick32",DTS_RIGHTALIGN | WS_TABSTOP,16,54,104,12
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Display Entries",ID_BTN_DISPLAY_ENTRIES,21,76,90,14
    GROUPBOX        "Settings ...",IDC_STATIC,7,101,120,174,0,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    LTEXT           "Assignment:",IDC_STATIC,16,113,102,10
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_ASSIGNMENT,16,124,97,60,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Starting Name:",IDC_STATIC,16,143,96,8
    COMBOBOX        ID_CMB_START_NAME,16,154,97,60,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    CONTROL         "Include All Dates",IDC_CHECK_INCLUDE_ALL_DATES_CHAIRMAN_READER,
                    "Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_MULTILINE | WS_TABSTOP,19,169,96,16
    CONTROL         "Ignore Local Speakers",IDC_CHECK_IGNORE_LOCAL,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_MULTILINE | WS_TABSTOP,19,182,96,19
    CONTROL         "&Avoid Conflicts",IDC_CHK_AVOID_CONFLICT,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,19,202,95,10
    LTEXT           "&Weeks to avoid:",ID_STATIC_WEEKS,30,215,94,8
    COMBOBOX        ID_CMB_NUM_WEEKS,42,227,39,44,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    PUSHBUTTON      "A&uto Assign",ID_BTN_AUTO_ASSIGN,21,251,90,14
    GROUPBOX        "Entries ...",IDC_STATIC_ENTRIES,134,9,272,248,0,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC_ASSIGN_GRID,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME | NOT WS_VISIBLE,141,22,258,204
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Show Conflicts",ID_BTN_SHOW_CONFLICTS,178,237,90,14
    CONTROL         "",ID_STATIC_KEY,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME | NOT WS_VISIBLE,277,230,122,21
    PUSHBUTTON      "Help",ID_BTN_HELP,134,261,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Print",ID_BTN_ASSIGN_PRINT,189,261,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Undo",ID_BTN_UNDO,245,261,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,301,261,50,14
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,357,261,50,14
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_ETCHEDVERT | NOT WS_VISIBLE,377,97,1,1
END
```

Here is the dynamic layout data:

```
ID_DLG_ASSIGN AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 100, 100,
    0, 0, 100, 100,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 100, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0
END
```

Now, there are two particular controls:

- `GROUPBOX        "Date Range ...",IDC_STATIC,7,9,120,91,0,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`
- `GROUPBOX        "Settings ...",IDC_STATIC,7,101,120,174,0,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`

If I unswitch the transparent flag and show the dialog and resize:

[image: Sized]

Whilst it looks weird, the two group boxes stay visible. But when I switch the transparency back on like it should have been and then show the dialog and resize it:

[image: Sized 2]

They vanish! What causes this? Confused. I stress, they are there when it is first displayed (the position restored). As soon as I size the problem happens. This is the `OnSize`:

```
void CAssignmentsDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
    CResizingDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    CRect rctControl;
    m_lblAssignGrid.GetWindowRect(rctControl);
    ScreenToClient(rctControl);
    m_Grid.MoveWindow(rctControl);
}
```

And `OnPaint`:

```
void CAssignmentsDlg::OnPaint() 
{
    //CResizingDialog::OnPaint();

    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    COLORREF    crTextHL, crBackHL;
    COLORREF    crTextOld, crBackOld;
    CString     strText;

    EstablishLegendPosition();

    crBackHL = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
    crTextHL = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT);

    dc.FillSolidRect(m_rcKey, crBackHL);

    crBackOld = dc.SetBkColor(crBackHL);
    crTextOld = dc.SetTextColor(crTextHL);

    strText.LoadString( IDS_STR_SAMPLE_CONFLICT );
    CFont l_font;
    l_font.CreateFont(14, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL,
        FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 0, 
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,   
        DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_ROMAN, _T("Arial"));

    CFont* l_old_font = dc.SelectObject(&l_font);

    dc.DrawText( strText, m_rcKey, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER );

    dc.SetBkColor(crBackOld);
    dc.SetTextColor(crTextOld);

    // Delete the font object. 
    dc.SelectObject(l_old_font);
    l_font.DeleteObject();

    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    rc.left = rc.right - ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL);
    rc.top = rc.bottom - ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);
    HTHEME ht = OpenThemeData(GetSafeHwnd(), L"STATUS");
    if (ht)
    {
        DrawThemeBackground(ht, dc, SP_GRIPPER, 0, &rc, nullptr);
        CloseThemeData(ht);
    }
    else
    {
        dc.DrawFrameControl(rc, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLSIZEGRIP);
    }
}
```

I moved the drawing of the gripper from the base base into this class just incase it was the problem. I don't get it.

Comment: I tried switching Windows Blinds off and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` was the culprit. Switch it off and resizing works correctly.